# CSRF token not found on deployed Laravel app

Tags: vuejs3, laravel-8, inertiajs, csrf-token

I have Laravel + Inertia + Vue3 app. My login page works ok locally, but when i deployed it (via git) to production server, when i try to access `/login` page i'm getting error:

```
CSRF token not found: https://laravel.com/docs/csrf#csrf-x-csrf-token
```

Only thing that is different is .env API_KEY and API_URL;

I did `php artisan storage:link` on remote, and cleared cache

Pages outside "auth" middleware work ok.

Does anybody have idea what to do?

tnx

Comment: Recheck your form if it sends the CSRF token properly.

Comment: i'm not getting to form. page doesn't load